# Can I use GroupWise to log my incoming phone calls?

Tags: groupwise

I want to track who called me and when and what action I took.

Instead of recording my incoming calls in a piece of paper (a tracking sheet), can I record this in Groupwise?  How?

Plus, can I use GroupWise to log my outgoing calls, too? I want to record who I called when and what was discussed.